# Как пропустить первые значения элементы в массиве в C#

Tags: c#, массивы, сортировка, числа

Хочу что вывод данных массива был

```
[i = 1]:  2 3 4 5
[i = 2]:  2 3
[i = 3]:  2
[i = 4]:
```

Вот мой код

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var array = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            int x = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length-x; i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"[i = {i}]: ");
                int cc = 1;
                for (int j = 0; j < array.Length-cc; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(array[j]);
                    Console.Write(' ');
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Но получается пока так(

```
[i = 0]: 1 2 3 4
[i = 1]: 1 2 3 4
[i = 2]: 1 2 3 4
[i = 3]: 1 2 3 4
```

помогите изменить код правильно, А до этого был такой код

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var array = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"[i = {i}]: ");
                
                for (int j = 0; j < array.Length-0-i; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(array[j]);
                    Console.Write(' ');
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}   Выводит он так значения 

[i = 0]: 1 2 3 4 5
[i = 1]: 1 2 3 4
[i = 2]: 1 2 3
[i = 3]: 1 2
[i = 4]: 1
```

Comment: измени `for (int i = 0;` на  `for (int i = 1;`

Comment: Опишите конкретно, что вы хотите сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь Linq, а именно методом Skip, который пропускает нужное кол-во элементов перечисления (List, массив, etc.):

```
var array = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    var skip = array.Skip(i + 1);
    string result = string.Join(" ", skip);
    Console.WriteLine($"[i = {i + 1}]: {result}");
}
```

Output:

> [i = 1]: 2 3 4
> [i = 2]: 3 4
> [i = 3]: 4
> [i = 4]:

Upd: Код без применения LINQ (по запросу из комментария):

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write($"[i = {i + 1}]: ");
    for (int a = 1; a < array.Length - i; a++)
    {
        Console.Write(array[a] + " ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за ваш труд, и за полученные новые знания, а как такой-же код,  расписать без Linq ?

Comment: @Грустьжизни Добавил в ответ код без LINQ (Но чем он вам не нравится?)

Comment: Просто для меня циклы это боль я хочу сними лучше по работать. И когда куча с кобок тоже. Но надо учится спан за ваши старания